# Why Launch Time range is large and if able to shorten?

Tags: apache-spark

We specified 700 executors and --executor-cores is 2 in the job submit parameters.
In the console I see there’s 1344 task for one stage.
The **Launch Time** range for the tasks is from 2015/01/09 02:55:54 to 2015/01/09 03:00:03 in one testing, cost over 4 mins. So we wonder if there any way to shorten the delay.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the application in local mode, I advise to try run the spark application on the Cluster and see if there is any improvement.

Comment: Yes, we already run the spark application in yarn cluster,  the cluster has about 600+ nodes, and it's shared and also have hadoop jobs run on it. We re-wrote our hadoop job to spark and expect to improve performance (The job is simple only one mapper and then reduce ), but we do not see much difference in the processing time. And then we see the spark task Launch Time is slower than corresponding hadoop map task, so we wonder if there any way to shorten the task delay so improve spark performance.